# How to dynamically fetch a file with a certain name in powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, scripting

I would like my script to fetch certain files from within multiple directories (location).

For Example:

**Set 1:**

Following files from `C:\test\ext`

```
20160830.ext  -- (CurrentDate - 1).ext
20160823.ext  -- (CurrentDate - 7).ext
20160802.ext  -- (CurrentDate - 28).ext
```

Following file from `C:\test\nxt`

```
20160830.nxt  -- (CurrentDate - 1).nxt
```

**Set 2:**

Following files from `C:\test2\ext` (These files have a prefix before the name)

```
IND20160830.ext  -- (INDCurrentDate - 1).ext
IND20160823.ext  -- (INDCurrentDate - 7).ext
IND20160802.ext  -- (INDCurrentDate - 28).ext
```

Following files from `C:\test2\nxt`

```
IND20160830.nxt  -- (INDCurrentDate - 1).nxt
```

I have got the current date converted into `yyyymmdd` format using the following command

```
$Curr_date = (get-date).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
```

Output: `20160831`

But I am unsure how to fetch the files as per conditions listed above from those directory as its got to be dynamic as the script will be schedule to run weekly and should fetch the files as per the above condition.

Comment: By fetch do you mean copy the files  to another location?

Comment: i have got the date format for Current Date -1, -7 and -28 days using (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd'). So thats done. I need to know how can i search & fetch the files with these dates.extensions.

Comment: @Jonas yes that's right Jonas so for example if (file is currentdate - 1.ext) then copy to destination

Comment: You will need to set conditions and parse through your test folders and copy the output to your destination.

Comment: @Jonas yes i understand that but that is exactly what i am not getting. 'Foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem $SourcePath))
{
    if($file.Name -eq $Previousday.ext)
    {
     
     Copy-Item -Path $file.fullname -Destination $Destination

    }

}'

Comment: can you please advise how to submit a code in here so that its formatted fine once the comment has been submitted. I tried to quote it but it didnt work.

Comment: `You mean like this?`

Comment: Browse to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74784/how-do-i-add-code-while-writing-comments

Comment: How is this linked to [tag:batch-file]? you are asking for a solution in PowerShell in the title and text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what i did:

1. I fetch the dates in the right format first 
   '$Date = (Get-date.AddDays(-1).TopString('yyyyMMdd')'
2. Then create another variable '$V1 = "$Date.ext"'
3. 'If($file.Name -eq $V1)
   {

   Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $Path

   }'

This works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is a small example of copying one of your files from `C:\test\ext` to a file called `Output` on the desktop.
Note the `""` around your file name. This means that the spaces in your file name have been excluded.

```
@ECHO OFF
xcopy "C:\test\ext\20160830.ext  -- (CurrentDate - 1).ext" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Output\"
pause
```

You need to find a way to do this to all of your files. Don't use dates if you already know the file name.

Comment: Thanks but the suggestions are very theoretical and something which i already know, i need some syntax related advice. However i have figured it out and its working. Thanks again for your support though.